# Where does /etc/inputrc come from?

Tags: bash, inputrc, readline

I'm just being curious about how or from what package the **/etc/inputrc** file is generated in an Ubuntu system. I've tried:

```
$ apt-file search /etc/inputrc
```

But it outputs nothing. No package assigned?

I've seen there exist a inputrc file in the libreadline6 and bash packages but neither of them seems to be responsible of it (unless I failed to see the steps who produce it in one of those packages).

Comment: Related: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=504793

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking more clear-fully at the **readline6** source package, more specifically at the **readline-common.postinst** file I discovered the file is copied at the *configure* step

```
if [ "$1" = "configure" ] && [ "$2" = "" ]; then
  install_from_default /usr/share/readline/inputrc /etc/inputrc
fi
```

I really don't understand why it's copied this way and not with some cp in the rules file or even in a debian/readline-common.install file.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt install readline-common` installs this file. It was missing for me in Docker, and this helped.