# How to navigate the terminal with the cursor keys

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, navigation

I've done an internet search for `ubuntu terminal navigation keys` but it didn't return anything helpful to me. In Windows (command prompt or GUI), you can go to the next or previous word by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> respectively, but these keys don't work in the Ubuntu terminal.

The only navigation keys I know that work are <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>. What are the navigation keys to quickly jump between words in Ubuntu's terminal?

Comment: Ctrl+Right and Ctrl+Left should navigate words by default, as defined in /etc/inputrc (in 16.04, see lines 44-50). Have you set up a custom inputrc or made any other changes to your terminal/shell setup? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @wjandrea It's vanilla Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-170-generic x86_64)

Comment: Unfortunately 14.04 is no longer supported unless you pay for ESM. You need to switch to a supported release, namely 16.04, 18.04, or 19.04. See [releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) on the wiki.

Comment: @wjandrea It's the version supplied by AWS. We can't change it as far as I know. Our production servers (in fact all our servers) are running it. The question is, does 14.04 support this style of navigation, and what are the keys?

Comment: In that case, contact AWS for support. I want to help, but the [relevant package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/readline-common) has been taken down so I can't even tell you what's in the default /etc/inputrc file ([/usr/share/readline/inputrc](https://askubuntu.com/a/549883/301745)). In any case, 14.04 is not supported so it's off-topic here.

Comment: The bash *shell* supports Ctrl+Left / Ctrl+Right - provided it is in the default `emacs` mode with default `inputrc` bindings. If you've changed to a different shell (or configured bash to use `vi` mode) then the behavior may be different.

Comment: @steeldriver I don't know enough to do tricky things like that. It's vanilla Ubuntu.

Comment: You're running Ubuntu on Amazon, but your question makes it sound like you're running it locally. If you're SSH'ing into an ubuntu instance, that doesn't necessarily mean you're using ubuntu's terminal. What program are you using to access the command line? Are you accessing it from a computer running Windows? A web browser? Most likely that is the question you want to be asking.

Comment: @steveantwan I'm using PuTTY to SSH in.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>right</kbd> will jump between words in the terminal. These key combinations don't work in vi, but it's a start!